# add to TAR and split archive of 147k files in a directory

Tags: linux, tar

I have to migrate a website where are 147.000 images files in a single folder. I try to compress with gzip / tar but exited without any error message, and the archive file is 0 byte long.

```
$ tar cvf - web/uploads/documents/*.* | split -b 1024m - documents.tgz.
```

> bash: /usr/bin/tar: Argument list too long

I think it's because of too many files I try to add at once. Now I'm looking for a solution to put files into seperated archive, each one with the starting letter of files (a.tar < abacus.jpeg, admire.png, amateur.gif, etc)

What command I have to use to do that?

Thank you in advance

Comment: @Kamil Maciorowski edited

Comment: OK. `-T -` reads from stdin. What was the stdin then? Can't you just archive the whole directory?

Comment: it was a "find ." but I've run "tar czvf backup.tar.gz *" in another directory and it stores files/subdirs correctly but It the image's folder doesn't

Comment: `*` where there are many files will hit `argument list too long` or similar. I meant `tar czvf backup.tar.gz the_directory` from the parent directory.

Comment: can you help me split the archive to 1GB slices? Is this the only way like that? "tar cvzf - dir/ | split -b 200m - sda1.backup.tar.gz."

Comment: Please compare [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310), identify your real goal and state it in the question ([edit]). At first you were "looking for a solution to put files into separated archive, each one with the starting letter". I thought this was only an idea for workaround because the original command did not work. We kinda fixed the command, but now your requirement is to split to 1GB slices anyway. The question should state this. Do not expand the question in comments. [Edit] the post, rebuild it to match your real goal.

Comment: @Kamil Maciorowski I hope the title "add to TAR and split archive of 147k files in a directory" helps to cover the issue now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below I'm answering the 147k part of the original question.

I'm assuming that if `web/uploads/documents/*.*` is your list of 147k files, then the tar option `-T` is what you need. Below is from the tar manpage

```
   -T, --files-from=FILE
          get names to extract or create from FILE
```

As with other options in tar, you can use `-` inplace of stdin/out as needed. So in this case using `-T -` will get tar to read the list of files from stdin.

If you don't give `ls` any wildcards, you can just pipe the output into `tar`like this

```
ls web/uploads/documents | tar cvf - -T - | split -b 1024m - documents.tgz.
```

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Interesting article. Obviously depends on whether you expect the input filenames to use any crazy characters. For a simple one-off task, where I know exactly what the filenames look like, I'd just use `ls`. If I was putting the code in a script where I don't know what users will do, I'd use `find`. This task looks like a one-off, but only @Roland will know if the input filenames are clean enough to just use `ls`.

Comment: 1., yeah, the archive will be built by:

tar cvf documents.tar --files-from /home/something/filelist.txt

2., and the filelist.txt will be created by:

find mysite/web/uploads/documents/ -name '*.*' -print >/home/something/filelist.txt

3., now that's what we can split to 1024MB pieces with:

split -b 1024M documents.tar documents.tar.

Answer (score 0):

First problem: if you want to include all the files from the directory into the .tgz archive, specifying the directory instead of files should work (unless there are any file/directory that doesn't match on the `*.*` blob and that you're trying to leave out of the archive).

Have you tryed this?:

```
tar cvf - web/uploads/documents | split -b 1024m - documents.tgz
```

Second problem: from @pmqs's answer, you can get a *.tgz archive for files starting by letters by doing something like:

```
for letter in {a..z}; do
  find web/uploads/documents -iname ${letter}\* | tar -T - -czf ${letter}-documents.tgz
done
```

This assumes that your file names start all with a lowercase letter from a to z, and will generate archives named a-documents.tgz, b-documents.tgz, etc.